# angular4.x, navigationEnd.url vs navigationEnd.urlAfterRedirects

Tags: angular

Any explain or doc about the difference between `navigationEnd.url` and `navigationEnd.urlAfterRedirects`?

Which one should I use if I want to write a `breadcrumb` component?

Comment: heh, just checked the source code, saying `/** @docsNotRequired */` on both `url` and `urlAfterRedirects`

Comment: yeah. I checked. what does this mean?

Comment: My guess is that `navigationEnd.url` is your current `url` and `navigationEnd.urlAfterRedirects` is `url` that you will be redirected to if you navigate to `navigationEnd.url`

Comment: I checked , it seems they are always equal.

Comment: Yeah I notice that as well on debug, I guess there is a case when they could be different otherwise  what is the reason of having two the same props which is always equal? Try to talk to ViktorSavkin on that. Also I think if you just use `navigationEnd.url ` for your case you should be fine.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It depends if you care about the URL that the user requested or the URL of the route that actually gets loaded.

If you define any routes with redirects, the two values will be different if the user navigates to a route that redirects to another route.

For example, take these routes (which components the routes load is not relevant, so they're excluded here):

```
{
  path: "",
  pathMatch: "full",
  redirectTo: "home"
},
{
  path: "home",
},
```

If the user navigates to `/home`, then `navigationEnd.url` and `navigationEnd.urlAfterRedirects` will both be `/home`.

If the user navigates to `/`, then navigationEnd.url will be `/` and navigationEnd.urlAfterRedirects will be `/home`.

Even if you don't implement redirects, try to use the value that is most relevant to the the functionality you are basing on the url because you don't want to run into strange bugs later on if you add redirects.